# Why Index Isn't Being Used In Query?

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

The query is as below:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED 
SELECT u0_.value AS value0, u1_.property_uri AS property_uri1, u2_.service_id AS sclr2, count(u0_.id) AS sclr3 
FROM usc_account_triple u0_ 
INNER JOIN usc_account_connection u3_ ON ((u0_.service_subscriber_id = u3_.account_2_id))
INNER JOIN usc_service_subscriber u2_ ON ((u3_.account_1_id = u2_.id)) 
INNER JOIN usc_property u1_ ON u0_.property_id = u1_.id AND (u1_.status = 1) 
WHERE (u1_.create_analytics = '2') AND (u0_.status = 1) AND (u3_.status = 1) 
      AND (u2_.status = 1) GROUP BY u0_.property_id, u0_.value, u2_.service_id;
```

Here, along with other table's index, I am trying to create index on table 'usc_service_subscriber' table as like below:

```
CREATE INDEX `temp` ON usc_service_subscriber(id, status, service_id);
```

But, unfortunately the index isn't getting selected by the optimizer. Here is what explain command return:

```
|  1 | SIMPLE | u2_ | eq_ref | PRIMARY,temp | PRIMARY | 8 | bootsat.u3_.account_1_id          | 1 | 100.00 | Using where
```

Any Idea why? Is there anything wrong with the combination or ordering of the index?

Comment: maybe you could try to force it to use the index http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html

Answer (score 0):

You can force the use of index using the syntax `FORCE INDEX (index_name)` but to my knowledge, in your case the index is not used because of too few rows to be selected.

Per your posted explain result, it looks like only 1 row to be fetched/selected and probably that's the very same reason index is not used.

See [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html) for more information on MySQL Index Hints.